# How to combine a multiple series bar chart and a line chart

Tags: android, achartengine

I'd like to combine a bar chart with 2 data series and a line chart in AChartEngine but I was not able to do that. In  the AChartEngine demo I found only an example which combines a single series bar chart and a line Chart (Combined temperature).

What I'd like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBq9w.jpg

If I define 3 series (2 for bar chart, 1 for line chart) in a dataset for a combined XY chart like this:
`ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartView(ctx, dataset, renderer, new String[] { BarChart.TYPE, BarChart.TYPE, LineChart.TYPE });`

...then I get this result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVozj.jpg

If I define 3 series and 2 chart types:
`ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartView(ctx, dataset, renderer, new String[] { BarChart.TYPE, LineChart.TYPE });`

...then I get an exception:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Dataset, renderer and types should be not null and the datasets series count should be equal to the types length

at org.achartengine.ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartView(ChartFactory.java:202)`

Do I misunderstand something or does AChartEngine simply not support a multiple series bar chart and a line chart in combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the "Combined temperature" example in the AChartEngine demo, you can keep a `LineChart` and a `BarChart` the way they are and add a new `BarChart`. The x axis values for the two bar charts should be a little bit different such as they don't overlap. For instance, if the `x` values should be `1` then the first bar chart could add the value at `0.75` and the second one at `1.25`. This way they will be rendered separately.

Also, set the main renderer bar spacing: `renderer.setBarSpacing(1);` means that the space between 2 items in the same series is equal to the width of one bar.

Comment: Thanks for your hint Dan. However your suggested approach makes overlap the bar series when I define the chart as combined XY chart like this:  
`new CombinedXYChart(dataset, renderer, new String[] { BarChart.TYPE, BarChart.TYPE, LineChart.TYPE });`
The plain bar chart works fine with multiple series dataset:
`new BarChart(dataset, renderer, BarChart.Type.DEFAULT)`
    
The same issue was reported here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195585

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: I suggested using a single bar chart with 2 series and a single line chart.

Comment: Dan, maybe I misunderstand you. I updated my post to be more precise on what issue I have. Thanks a lot for your patience and great support!

Comment: You are correct, I've just checked that. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I will try to adapt CombinedXYChart and come up with a proposal how this feature could be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

See this : http://tapt007.hubpages.com/hub/Android-Combined-Charts Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. This article explains the combination of a bar chart with one data series and a line chart. What I'm looking for is a bar chart with **two** data series combined with a line chart.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is dead